# Colocar valor padrão na coluna

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java, hql

Preciso deixar um valor default nessa coluna da tabela, estou fazendo o mapeamento das persistências com o Hibernate (resumindo o banco é criado de acordo com o HQL/JPA que eu defino nos domains.

Como faço para setar um valor padrão para a coluna ?

```
@NotEmpty(message="O campo foto não pode ficar em branco !")
@Column(name = "foto_usuario", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String foto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o colega Wagner postou, um ex:

```
@NotEmpty(message="O campo foto não pode ficar em branco !")
@Column(name = "foto_usuario", nullable = false, columnDefinition="varchar(50) default 'same one value'")
private String foto;
```

ou, aqueles callback methods do Hibernate, ex:

```
@PrePersist
void defaultValue() {
   foto = "sua imagem aqui";
}
```

Agora sendo sincero, se é um valor default por que não atribuir direto no bean?

```
@NotEmpty(message="O campo foto não pode ficar em branco !") 
@Column(name = "foto_usuario", length = 50, nullable = false) 
private String foto = "sua foto default aqui";
```

Comment: Mas se eu colocar ele direto no bean igual teu último exemplo, quando o cara não colocar nada, ele vai pegar aquele ali ? e quando ele setar uma foto vai a que ele mandou, é a mesma coisa ? funciona como default ?

Comment: Toda vez que você instânciar um objeto ele irá ficar com aquela propriedade preenchida, caso esteja buscando do banco ele terá o valor que foi atribuído anteriormente.

Comment: Acho que serei mais claro agora, eu preciso que o usuário coloque uma foto de url no campo de cadastro, se ele não colocar eu quero uma padrão da nossa empresa, qual você acha que é a maneira mais adequada para fazer isso ?

Comment: as três forma da certo, eu deixaria configurado direto no objeto porque essa imagem default não vai mudar, é uma daquelas imagens fantasmas de cadastro que serve para todo mundo, mas se você tem uma imagem desta para usuário masculino e outra default para usuário feminino ai você não escapa de ter que usar o @PrePersiste

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
@Column(name="suacoluna", columnDefinition="float default 0")
```